# Cannot access 'app' before initialization [VS code javascript webdev]

Tags: node.js

This is my server file called app.js and everytime I run node app.js, it gives me an error, "Cannot access 'app' before initialization" Can anyone help me understand why and how I can fix this? Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();


const path = require('path');

const express = require('express'); // import express package
const app = express();

const homeRouter = require('./routes/home'); //refers to the home.js file in routes
const errorRouter = require('./routes/404'); //refers to the 404.js file in routes


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use('/', (request, response, next) => {
  response.send("<h1> Welcome to my Project </h1>");
  next();
});


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(homeRouter);
app.use(errorRouter);


app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you're sharing that'd cause a `Cannot access 'app' before initialization` error - are you sure it's not coming from the `homeRouter` or `errorRouter`? Also, you **should not** be calling `next()` after you call `response.send(...)` - `next` should only be used if you're trying to pass control to the next middleware function, but in your case you're ending the request with `response.send(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine. Check refering app in router files or share those files so that I can give a look.

Btw, your middleware sending response, so if your router calls res.send or anything like that will cause an error.